# Changing background color of the row on click of a link 

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, richdatatable

I am using Richfaces 4. I have a `<rich:datatable />` with 4 columns. In that, first column is a `<a4j:commandlink />` . I need to change the background color of the entire row when I click on the link. On click of the link I am calling action listener, and `oncomplete` I am rerendering the page. How do I change the color of the clicked row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add on your link the onclick method :

```
<rich:column>
  <a4j:commandlink onclick="changeBackground(this)" ...
</rich:column>
```

The Script (Using jQuery) to find the tr of the cell and apply style :

```
<script>
    function changeBackground(element){
      jQuery(element).parents('tr:first').addClass('backgroundRed');
    }
</script>
```

and the css for example

```
.backgroundRed {
    color: #555658;
    background-color: red;
}
```

You can check [this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173262/change-background-color-of-a-row-in-richdatatable/7175499#7175499) to further information.