# change background color of a row in rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

i have a row in rich:datatable, which has a link in one of its column. Onclick of this click i need to change the background color of the selected row. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following code:

```
<a4j:form id="myfrm">
<rich:dataTable id="myTbl" value="#{myBean.tblData}" var="tblData">
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Col1</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{tblData}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Col2</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{tblData}" />
    </rich:column>
    <a4j:support event="onRowClick" oncomplete="highlightSingleRow(this)"/>
</rich:dataTable>
</a4j:form>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
function highlightSingleRow(col) {
    jQuery(col).parent().parent().find('tr').removeClass('highlight-row');
    jQuery(col).parent().addClass('highlight-row');
}
```

CSS:

```
.highlight-row {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

The above example would highlight the row when it is clicked.

To do it on a link you could do something like:

```
<rich:dataTable id="myTbl" value="#{myBean.tblData}" var="tblData">
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Col1</f:facet>
        <h:outputLink onclick="highlightSingleRow(this)" value="#">
            <h:outputText value="link" />
        </h:outputLink>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Col2</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{tblData}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

and then change your javascript to:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
function highlightSingleRow(lnk) {
    jQuery(lnk).parent().parent().parent().find('tr').removeClass('highlight-row');
    jQuery(lnk).parent().parent().addClass('highlight-row');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on your link the onclick method :

```
<rich:column>
  <h:outputLink onclick="changeBackground(this)" value="#">
    <h:outputText value="link" />
  </h:outputLink>
</rich:column>
```

The Script (Using jQuery) to find the tr of the cell and apply style :

```
<script>
    function changeBackground(element){
      jQuery(element).parents('tr:first').addClass('backgroundRed');
    }
</script>
```

and the css for example

```
.backgroundRed {
    color: #555658;
    background-color: red;
}
```