# Change DataTable row color on checkbox selection

Tags: primefaces

I have a `<p:dataTable>` , with a checkbox on the last column. I want to color the rows of the table based on the status of the checkbox.

```
<p:dataTable var="acs" value="#{myBean.listaRevogaveis}"
emptyMessage="#{rotulo.mensagemSemDados}" paginator="true"
rows="10" id="tableacs"
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
<p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="#{acs.nome}"
filterBy="#{acs.nome}">
<h:outputText value="#{acs.nome}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Address" sortBy="#{acs.address}" filterMatchMode="contains"
filterBy="#{acs.address}" filterMaxLength="8">
<h:outputText value="#{acs.address}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Perfil" sortBy="#{acs.cdPerfil}"
filterBy="#{acs.cdPerfil}"  filterMaxLength="2">
<h:outputText value="#{acs.cdPerfil}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Cadastramento">
<h:outputText value="#{acs.tsSolicitacao}">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Concedido">
<h:outputText value="#{acs.concedidoPor}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Revogar">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{acs.ativo}" >
<p:ajax event="valueChange" oncomplete="toggleColor(this, #{acs.ativo}" listener="#{myBean.checkBox}" update="@form"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

So on the toggling of `#{acs.ativo}` I want that row to receive a different background color.

Following the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173262/change-background-color-of-a-row-in-richdatatable) I tried to add this to my xhtml:

```
<style type="text/css">
.linhaDestacada {   background-color: red !important;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleColor(col, status) {

        var linha = jQuery(col).parent();

        if(status) {
            linha.removeClass('linhaDestacada');
        } else {
            linha.addClass('linhaDestacada');           
            }
        }

</script>
```

But that's of no use. I put some alerts to see if the function was being called, it is. However, trying to see the tagName, or any property of the `linha` variable returns null.

There is another interesting point, the callback is being called with the previous value of the checkbox. When box is checked, javascript `toggleColor()` is receiving false on the `status`, when its unchecked it receives true.

How can I make the row background toggle together with the checkbox toggle?

Comment: if someone can help me with the formatting of the code blocks, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there were a TON of bugs and problems in that one.

**First:**

primefaces sets the background of the rows to a blank image (depending on the skin). you have to override the `url()` of the background, so the CSS should look like:

.linhaDestacada {   background: url('') red !important;}

**Second:**

Calling the javascript from the ajax tag was causing the jQuery to find nulls (dunno why). move the callback to the checkbox tag, using its `onchange` attribute.

The final javascript fragment was:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleColor(col, status) {

        var linha = jQuery(col).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();

        if(status) {
            linha.removeClass('linhaDestacada');
            //alert("remove " + linha.html());
        } else {
                linha.addClass('linhaDestacada');
                //alert("add "  + linha.html());

            }
        }

     </script>
```

**Third:**

Updating the WHOLE form is a no-no (the css class you added with javascript was being erased)... you should update only what really matters (in this case, the checkbox and the command button.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{acs.ativo}" onchange="toggleColor(this, #{acs.ativo})">
    <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{myBean.checkBox}" update="@this :formAcesso:btnRevogaNuke" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

**Fourth:**

the commandButton was not rendering. It would be updated on the ajax response, but the browser did not display it. Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573190/jsf-primefaces-update-attribute-does-not-update-component), and moved the id `btnRevogaNuke` on the encapsulating element:

```
<h:panelGroup id="btnRevogaNuke" layout="block">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-alert" value="Confirmar rendered="#{myBean.confirmar()}" style="margin-left:600px;" action="#{acessoBean.revogaTodos()}" process="@this @form" update="@form" />
</h:panelGroup>
```